# Can not install semanage tool on RedHat virtual machine

Tags: mongodb, port, redhat

I'm trying to [change the MongoDB default port](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/) on my AWS Virtual Machine but `semanage` is not found on the server

`semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27042`

*-bash: semanage: command not found*

Trying to find the package that provides `semanage` fails.

`dnf whatprovides semanage`

*Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhui-client-config-server-8':
Curl error (58): Problem with the local SSL certificate for https://rhui3.eu-west-3.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/mirror/protected/rhui-client-config/rhel/server/8/x86_64/os [could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)]*

*Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhui-client-config-server-8': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (58): Problem with the local SSL certificate for https://rhui3.eu-west-3.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/mirror/protected/rhui-client-config/rhel/server/8/x86_64/os [could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)]*

`dnf update` works and the system is up-to-date

*Last metadata expiration check: 0:42:00 ago on Tue 21 Jul 2020 10:11:35 AM UTC.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!*

**Additional informations :**

`cat /etc/redhat-release`

Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa)

`dnf repolist`

*repo id / repo name*

*mongodb-org-4.2 / MongoDB Repository*

*rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms / Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream from RHUI (RPMs)*

*rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms / Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS from RHUI (RPMs)*

*rhui-client-config-server-8 / Red Hat Update Infrastructure 3 Client Configuration Server 8*

Could you help me to install semanage please ? Thanks.

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Thank you Chris Williams. I asked the same question 2 days ago on Super User but I got no answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

1.dnf install policycoreutils-python-utils
2. dnf provides semanage (This displays the same result as above-the path)
3. yum provides /usr/sbin/semanage
4. yum install policycoreutils-python

I fixed my issue using this.

You can also refer this link:
https://www.ostechnix.com/linux-troubleshooting-semanage-command-not-found-in-centos-7rhel-7/

Comment: Thanks Divyani Singh. Your solution works for semanage, but now I need to install screen and I encounter the same problem.

Comment: Screen has been deprecated in RHEL 8 onwards, you can try using tmux instead of screen. You can check the same here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4136481